# Sharing feature recreation with UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uitoolbar

I'm currently trying to recreate the sharing feature seen in [Hacker News](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hacker-news/id514166419?ls=1&mt=8) in the AppStore.

Screenshots [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/khwxizvhjl8rs4v/2012-05-22%2015.51.51.png) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9w1nhts4y56z4h/2012-05-22%2015.51.53.png).

I know that they use a UIToolbar, and when the user taps the Share-Button, they somehow move the view up and show another view under the UIToolbar. But I have no idea, how they:

1. Move the view up
2. And then show another view.

Do you have any pointers or code samples for me? It would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out UIView animations. Just add the sharing view below the visible screen, then create an animation that slides both your new view and the view above it up into position. There is plenty of sample code for view animations on SO.